# Cursor stored procedure Mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure, cursor

Estou dentro de um cursor que tem 10 rows de resultado.
2 rows percentem á um numero. exemplo: `1,2 = 1, 3,4 = 2, 5,6 = 6, 7,8 = 9 , 9,10 = 3.`

Como faço dentro do cursor somar só os valores que correspondem ao mesmo numero?

Esse  é o meu `FETCH` do cursor, eu tenho 10 rows dentro dele, o spv_total_item é de uma spv_moeda_id especifica e eu quero somar quando as spv_moeda_id forem iguais, como faço isso?

```
FETCH cursor_comissao INTO SPV_COMISSAO_ID, SPV_COMPRA_ID, SPV_PERCENTUAL, SPV_MOEDA_ID, SPV_DATA_CAMBIO, SPV_TOTAL_ITEM;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficaria muito agracecido se alguém me ajudasse nessa lógica.

Tentei, mas na primeira vez que vai rodar a row, a `spv_moeda_check` é nulla, e só no final do loop que ela vai ter um valor..

```
 OPEN cursor_comissao;


-- INICIANDO A VARIAVEL DURAÇÃO DO LOOP PARA 0;
SET SPV_DURACAO = 0;

loop_comissoes: LOOP

FETCH cursor_comissao INTO SPV_COMISSAO_ID, SPV_COMPRA_ID, SPV_PERCENTUAL, SPV_MOEDA_ID, SPV_DATA_CAMBIO, SPV_TOTAL_ITEM;    


  IF CURSOR_FIM = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE loop_comissoes;
    END IF; 

    IF SPV_DURACAO = SPV_LOOP THEN
       SET CURSOR_FIM = 1;
       LEAVE loop_comissoes;
    END IF;

    IF SPV_COMISSAO_ID = SPV_ID_CHECK THEN
        SPV_TOTAL_ITEM = SPV_TOTAL_ITEM + SPV_TOTAL_ITEM;
        ITERATE loop_comissoes;
    END IF;



    CALL SP_CONVERTE_REAIS_DATA(SPV_TOTAL_ITEM,SPV_MOEDA_ID,SPV_DATA_CAMBIO,SPV_TOTAL_ITEM);

-- SETANDO O CAMPO VALOR DA ROW ATUAL DO LOOP;
    UPDATE cliente_compra_comissao SET valor = SPV_TOTAL_ITEM WHERE id = SPV_COMISSAO_ID;       

    SET SPV_DURACAO = SPV_DURACAO + 1;
    SET SPV_TOTAL_ITEM = 0;
    SET SPV_ID_CHECK = SPV_COMISSAO_ID;
END LOOP loop_comissoes;
CLOSE cursor_comissao;
CLOSE cursor_comissao_id;
```

Comment: Em qual banco é isso?

Comment: opa desculpa, phpMyAdmin

Comment: Adiciona a tag do mysql na pergunta :)

Comment: tag adicionada, rs

Comment: Estou confuso. Qual a relação da tabela anexada, com o comando de `FETCH`?

Comment: Essa tabela são os valores que vão entrar em cada variavel do `FETCH`, na mesma ordem, eu coloquei pra entenderem o que estou precisando, o meu cursor vai rodar cada linha desse resultado, mas o que eu preciso é que quando o id de cada linha for igual, ele some os valores.
Seria mais ou menos algo do tipo, eu preciso que ele armazene o valor do id, da linha anterior para verificar na proxima linha se é igual, se for ele soma, se não ele armazena o novo valor e volta pro começo.. algo do tipo..

Comment: Agora saquei a lógica.

Comment: Estou a 3 horas tentando montar uma lógica em cima disso, mas não consigo..Fiz algo aqui, mas o problema é que não consigo armazenar a primeira vez da moeda, então não passa do if, pq na primeira vez que for rodar a row, a `spv_moeda_check` vai ser nulla;